# redirect from old page - 302, 303 or 403 forbidden

Tags: redirect, seo, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-303

I create the site about realty.
It has three page about one item (flat)

/flat/item/1   -main page about flat
/flat/gallery/1 -photos
/flat/map/1 -map

Customer wants that if flat is out of stock then two pages(gallery, map) have unaccesible for view.

I want to know. What kind of status code I have to set 403 or 404?
May be 302, 303 and redirect to /flat/item/1?

Comment: So you can still see the main information for the property after it has sold, but you can't look at the photos anymore? Sounds like a strange requirement. If the property has sold it probably shouldn't show up in the listings at all, and any links to it should redirect to a page that helps the consumer find another property in that area. Maybe talk with your customer and try to clarify the requirements, this sounds like a misunderstanding or something that hasn't been fully thought through.

Comment: I forgot to tell about deal. It is rent. Rent time may be from 1 day to several month.

Comment: That's a different story. The way most of the vacation rental industry does it, you can still see all of the property details, you just can't book it right away. Usually they'll list similar properties, and the renter can contact either the site owner or the property manager to find a similar property, sometimes they'll show an availability calendar, etc. Maybe your client might be happier with a solution like this? (I worked in vacation rentals for a few years.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to redirect, you should be using 410 ("Gone"). This means that the resource  is permanently no longer available.

If you want to redirect the gallery and map to the main page, use code 301 ("Moved Permanently").